# Не читаются все данные из файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы

Не знаю как записать имя и фамилию в разные поля класса, типа `string`. Читаю из бинарного файла.
На данный момент записывает только первое, а именно имя (т.к. в буфер читается из файла только одно имя, фамилия в сам буфер `buf` - не приходит).

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class reader_info {
public:

void print_readers() {
    cout << name <<"\t"<< surname << endl;
}
void out_all_readers() {
    ifstream file;
    file.open("data_base.txt");
    reader_info reader;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        system("cls");
        size_t len = 0;

        while (file.read((char*)&len, sizeof(len))) {
            char* buf = new char[len];         // Выделение буфера для чтения
            file.read(buf, len);  
            
            delete[]buf;
            reader.print_readers();
            
        }
        
    }else cout << "[ERROR] Не могу открыть файл!" << endl;
    
    file.close();
}

private:
    string name = "",
        surname = "",
        books = "";
    int book_count = 0;

};
```

Comment: Ну в данном коде вы читаете из файла число (видимо, длину имени), а далее только имя. Покажите формат файла из которого читаете

Comment: Кроме того, вы открываете бинарный файл как текстовый - что тоже нехорошо...

Comment: @selfishCrawler, в самом файле ничего не видно. Я записываю в него поля класса (string). При помощи метода file.write((char*)&reader_info,sizeof(reader)); reader- объект класса

Comment: Посмотрите на [этот](https://pastebin.com/2VsMbhCr) пример, может он натолкнет Вас на мысль

Comment: @SelfishCrawler,  у меня изначально так читался файл, но была проблема с его закрытием, выдавалась ошибка. Написал тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222627/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0 закрыли ссылаясь на дубликат

Comment: Хм, онлайн компилятор не ругнулся и вышел с кодом 0, а вижак вылетает действительно. Тогда [вот такой](https://pastebin.com/UUk7R38K) пример. Вручную читаем все поля

Comment: @SelfishCrawler а что делать если объектов очень много?

Comment: @War_Never_Changes а что конкретно не подходит в этом примере под множество объектов? Вы можете задавать массив любой длины, это не важно там